# How to Join two table in Code first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

i have two table, User and Friendship. i want to join this two tables so that the column TheirFriends which have UserID of all friends will have some attribute that is in User. that is i want to get each friend  with all their attribute.
Output will look like this 
Theirfriends  firstname LastName UserPicture

i need this linq  and lambda expression.

User:

```
public class User
{

    public String UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string UserPicture { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public String Interest { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
```

FriendShip

```
 public class FriendShip
{

    public int FriendShipID { get; set; }
    public string TheirFriends { get; set; }

    public String UserID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that the string `TheirFriends` represents something like a collection with a separator, like "Jim;John;Diana" and those names are `UserIDs`? And what is then the `UserID` property in the `FriendShip` class?

Comment: @slauma                                                          when a user add a friend is going to insert The userID of his friend in TheirFriend column and his own userID in UserID in the friendship table. so whenever i search particular user with UserID in Friendship table i will return all his or her friends. Normally when i do this in sql i use views to join them.

Comment: You should go through the EF/MVC tutorial (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-(data) ) which shows how to to this and more.

Comment: @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com: The link in your comment above me is broken (URL looks incomplete).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
var usersWithFriends = context.Users
    .GroupJoin(context.FriendShips, u => u.UserID, f => f.UserID, (u, f) => new
    {
        User = u,
        Friends = f.Join(context.Users, f1 => f1.TheirFriends, u1 => u1.UserID,
            (f1, u1) => u1)
    })
    .ToList();
```

The result is a collection of anonymous objects and each element has a `User` property with a user and a `Friends` collection which contains all users which are friends of the given user. Because of the `GroupJoin` the result also contains users without friends (`Friends` collection is empty in this case). Roughly like so:

```
Element[0]:
    User -> "Jim"
    Friends -> "John" + "Diana"
Element[1]:
    User -> "John"
    Friends -> empty
Element[2]:
    User -> "Diana"
    Friends -> "John"
```

But this is not the Entity-Framework way to work with such a model. You should actually have a navigation property in your `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //...

    public ICollection<User> Friends  { get; set; }
}
```

And a many-to-many relationship between the users:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Friends)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(x =>
    {
        x.MapLeftKey("UserID");
        x.MapRightKey("TheirFriends");
        x.ToTable("FriendShips");
    });
```

`FriendShips` would be just a join table in the database (without a `FriendShipID` column, `UserID` and `TheirFriends` build a composite key instead) and not an entity in your model. `User` is your only entity. Then you could achieve the same result a lot easier:

```
var usersWithFriends = context.Users.Include(u => u.Friends).ToList();
```

Not only less lines of code but also a lot easier to read and understand. EF will care about the complex joining and grouping in the database when the query is translated into SQL.

**Edit**

You can add relationships (= rows in the link table `FriendShips`) by adding an existing user to the `Friends` collection:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var user = context.Users.Single(u => u.UserID == "John");
    var friend = context.Users.Single(u => u.UserID == "Diana");

    user.Friends = new HashSet<User>();
    user.Friends.Add(friend);

    context.SaveChanges(); // will write a new row into the join table
}
```

Likewise you can remove a relationship (remove row from join table):

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var user = context.Users.Include(u => u.Friends)
        .Single(u => u.UserID == "John");
    var friend = user.Friends.Single(u => u.UserID == "Diana");

    user.Friends.Remove(friend);

    context.SaveChanges(); // will delete a row from the join table
}
```

It's also possible without querying the users from the database since you have the primary key values:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var user = new User { UserID = "John" };
    var friend = new User { UserID = "Diana" };

    context.Users.Attach(user);
    context.Users.Attach(friend);

    user.Friends = new HashSet<User>();
    user.Friends.Add(friend);

    context.SaveChanges(); // will write a new row into the join table
}

using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var user = new User { UserID = "John" };
    var friend = new User { UserID = "Diana" };

    user.Friends = new HashSet<User>();
    user.Friends.Add(friend);

    context.Users.Attach(user);
    // attaching friend is not necessary, it is already attached with user

    user.Friends.Remove(friend);

    context.SaveChanges(); // will delete row from the join table
}
```

Comment: @JED: the table will only have two columns (UserID and TheirFriends) which build a key together.

Comment: this work fine but dont know how to add data to friendship table.

Comment: i have everything working but i can't insert data into the friendships table that has UserID and Thierfriends. how do i go about this. thanks

Comment: @JED: I have added two examples for adding/removing relationships. For more details or problems, please create a new question (it costs nothing). We are already moving away from your original question.

Comment: @JED - You should go through the EF/MVC tutorial (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-(data) ) which shows how to to this and more.

Comment: @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com: the link is broken. i will like to have a place to learn this from scratch. thanks