# How to model users and post addresses to find the city by zip code?

Tags: c#, database-design, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-code-first

I want to be able to load the city as related data on a user, based on the user's zip code. I understand that it not recommended to use the zip code itself as a key, as it might change in the future.

I have some models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PostAddress { get; set; } // Street, c/o., apartment number, etc.
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    // More properties ...
}

public class City
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment, I'm getting the city in a separate query, after obtaining the user's zip code.

In the end, I want to make queries like this:

```
var User = await db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id)
    .Include(c => c.City)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

... but I don't know how I should link the two tables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Join two table in Code first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647161/how-to-join-two-table-in-code-first-approach)

Comment: @Pixelmonster No, I know how related data works. But as far as I can see, my case is not as clear cut as to just have `public City City { get; set; }` on the user model.

Comment: @Pixelmonster Turns out, it really was that clear cut. I think I was over complicating it in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply the `[ForeignKey]` attribute to the navigation property and [Key] attribute to `Id` property in the `City` class to make it a key property:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PostAddress { get; set; } // Street, c/o., apartment number, etc.

    public int CityId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    public City City { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

For addition information see [Data Annotations - ForeignKey Attribute in EF 6 & EF Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: It was simpler than I thought. It was sufficient to just add the relation. No need for the annotations. I was over complicating the problem in my head, I think...

Comment: @Stian: By the way, I would prefer to use `int` for key column instead of  `Guid`.[Guid or Int as a primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4593873/6630084)

Comment: Yes, I have changed it to `int`. I use `Guid` for users and other entities in my db, but I agree `int` is better suited for the `City` model.